# How to add item to dropdowns using javascript and bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I've fetched the all regions for current date times and I want to add all of theese 387 regions to my bootstrap dropdown. Basically how to add items to bootstrap dropdowns using javascript. This is the basic html code:

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Haven't you tried anything? What about a JS for loop, using a `.createElemente()` inside?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this, make sure the regions are not of user input since this adds html.

```
const div = document.querySelector('.dropdown-menu');
const regions = ['Europe', 'America'];
regions.forEach(region => {
    div.innerHTML += `<a class="dropdown-item" href="#">${region}</a>`;
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use proper DOM management in JavaScript by creating the [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object using [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement) and leveraging [`appendChild`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild) to insert it into the DOM underneath your parent `div.dropdown-menu`:

```js
function addItems() {
  var numberOfItems = 5;
  for (var i = 0; i<numberOfItems; i++) {
    var ele = document.createElement("a");
    ele.classList = "dropdown-item";
    ele.href = "#";
    ele.innerText = "" + i;
    document.querySelector(".dropdown-menu").appendChild(ele);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
  </div>
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="addItems()">Add List Items</button>
</div>
```

Just to be clear, you'll have to adapt this example to fit the structure of the data you've sourced independently. It wasn't possible to tailor a solution to your specific situation since you didn't add any information about how you're currently receiving the data.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution

```js
function func() {
  /*storing item names in an array*/
  var region=['region1','region2','region3','region4','etc'];

  for(var i=0; i<region.length; i++){

    var item = document.createElement("a");
    item.setAttribute("class","dropdown-item");
    item.href = "#"; 
    var node = document.createTextNode(region[i]); /*fetching name of the items*/
    item.appendChild(node);
    document.getElementsByClassName('dropdown-menu')[0].appendChild(item);

  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.15.0/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="dropdown">

  <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    Dropdown button
  </button>
  
  <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
  
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
    <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
    
  </div>
  
  <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" onclick="func()">
     Add Items
  </button>
  
</div>
```