# append to dropdown on loop

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap dropdown what I want is to loop to a certain number and append `li` with each loop number inside but it is not working. How can I fix it? Thanks in advance.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  console.log(i)
  $('.dropdown-menu ul').append(`<li><a class="dropdown-item">test ${i}</a></li>`)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="dropdown">
  <button class="btn btn-secondary w-100 d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown">test</button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton1">
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add item to dropdowns using javascript and bootstrap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57189122/how-to-add-item-to-dropdowns-using-javascript-and-bootstrap)

Comment: The issue here is that the selector `.dropdown-menu ul` should be `ul.dropdown-menu`. See my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The selector for the `ul` is incorrect. It should be `ul.dropdown-menu`

`.dropdown-menu ul` will try to find a `ul` element inside any element that has the class `dropdown-menu`.

`ul.dropdown-menu` will find a ul element that has `dropdown-menu` class. This is what you want.

Try the following snippet.

```
<script>
    let ul = $('ul.dropdown-menu');
    console.log(ul);
    for (var i = 0; i < 22; i++) {
        console.log(i);
        let li = $(`<li><a class="dropdown-item">test ${i}</a></li>`);
        ul.append(li);
    }
</script>
```